# Loop to create table relations in Access VBA

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

I created one table relation with the following code.

```
Dim rel As New Relation
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set db = CurrentDb

rel.Attributes = dbRelationDontEnforce + dbRelationRight
rel.Name = "RelationName"
rel.Table = "tblParent"
rel.ForeignTable = "tblChild"

Set fld = rel.CreateField("FieldID")

fld.Name = "FieldID"
fld.ForeignName = "FieldID"
rel.Fields.Append fld
db.Relations.Append rel
```

I tried to loop it to create multiple relations from a query "QryRelaDict" as follows. It created the first relation in the first iteration and in the second iteration it stopped at `rel.Attributes = dbRelationEnforce` with

> run time error 3219: invalid operation

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim daRs As DAO.Recordset    
Dim rel As New Relation
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set db = CurrentDb
Set daRs = db.OpenRecordset("QryRelaDict")

Do While Not daRs.EOF

    Debug.Print daRs!tblPare & "-" & daRs!tblChil

    rel.Attributes = dbRelationEnforce 
    rel.Name = daRs!tblPare & "-" & daRs!tblChil & "-" & daRs!AAA
    rel.Table = daRs!tblPare
    rel.ForeignTable = daRs!tblChil

    Set fld = rel.CreateField(daRs!AAA)

    fld.Name = daRs!AAA
    fld.ForeignName = daRs!AAA

    rel.Fields.Append fld
    db.Relations.Append rel

    daRs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Inside your loop, add `Set rel = New Relation`.

Comment: yes..........;)

Comment: @davidzxc574 This question still appears to be open despite having an answer. Marking an answer gives you points and closes the question so people don't think you still need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question needs an answer. It was found in the comments:

> Inside your loop, add Set rel = New Relation

EXAMPLE:

```
   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim daRs As DAO.Recordset    
   Dim rel As Relation
   Dim fld As DAO.Field

   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set daRs = db.OpenRecordset("QryRelaDict")

   Do While Not daRs.EOF
        Set rel = New Relation
        Debug.Print daRs!tblPare & "-" & daRs!tblChil

        rel.Attributes = dbRelationEnforce 
        rel.Name = daRs!tblPare & "-" & daRs!tblChil & "-" & daRs!AAA
        rel.Table = daRs!tblPare
        rel.ForeignTable = daRs!tblChil

        Set fld = rel.CreateField(daRs!AAA)

        fld.Name = daRs!AAA
        fld.ForeignName = daRs!AAA

        rel.Fields.Append fld
        db.Relations.Append rel

        daRs.MoveNext
   Loop
```